# AoT and function factory (Dynamic Route Templates)

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm trying to make an [UrlMatcher](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher) factory

```ts
export const dummyMatcher: UrlMatcher = matchUrlFn(sitemap as any, 'dummy');

export const routes: Routes = [
  { matcher: dummyMatcher, component: DummyComponent },
  { path: '**', component: DummyComponent },
];
```

But this doesn't work with AoT... **How do we handle function factories with AoT?**

I tried

```ts
export function dummyMatcher(): UrlMatcher { return routeMatcher(sitemap as any, 'dummy'); }
```

but compiler is complaining:

> Type '{ matcher: () => UrlMatcher; component: typeof DummyComponent; }...' is not assignable to type 'Route[]'.

---

Use case:

I need to match web pages (described in `NavigationNode[]`) and render them in specific template components. Page can have multiple urls (for migration purposes, localized urls, etc.). 
Here's the matching logic:

```ts
import { UrlSegment, UrlSegmentGroup, Route, UrlMatchResult } from '@angular/router';
import { inArray } from '@core/utils';

export interface NavigationNode {
  ...
  title?: string;
  template?: string;
  urls?: string[];
}

/**
 * https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher
 */
export const UrlMatcherFactory = (conditions) =>
  (segments: UrlSegment[], group: UrlSegmentGroup, route: Route): UrlMatchResult =>
    conditions(segments) ? ({ consumed: segments }) : null;

export const matchUrl = (nodes: NavigationNode[], template?: string) =>
  (segments: UrlSegment[]) => nodes
    .filter(node => template ? node.template === template : true)
    .some(node => inArray(node.urls)(`/${segments.join('/')}`));

export const matchUrlFn= (nodes: NavigationNode[], template?: string) =>
  UrlMatcherFactory(matchUrl(nodes, template));
```

This can be easily extended to use different matching, for example Regex:

```ts
export const matchRegex = (nodes: NavigationNode[]) =>
  (segments: UrlSegment[]) => nodes
    .some(node => /\w+\/xyz/\d{1, 3}/.test(node.title)); /* bad example (: */

export const matchRegexFn = (nodes: NavigationNode[], template?: string) =>
  UrlMatcherFactory(matchRegex(nodes));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`matcher` property should implement `UrlMatcher` type:

```typescript
export declare type UrlMatcher = (segments: UrlSegment[], group: UrlSegmentGroup, route: Route) => UrlMatchResult;
```

so i would suggest you to change code like:

```typescript
export function dummyMatcher(segments: UrlSegment[], group: UrlSegmentGroup, route: Route): UrlMatchResult {
  const factory = matchUrlFn(sitemap as any, 'dummy');
  return factory(segments, group, route);
}
```

Comment: Yea, this works and it lead me to final version `export function dummyMatcher(): UrlMatcher { return routeMatcher(sitemap as any, 'dummy').apply(this, arguments); }`... I'm trying to keep it light, since there are several routes with matchers, so isolating logic in another place makes it easier to work with. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For new people facing the problem with AOT compiler 
you need to move fat arrow function to normal ES5 function & `export` it (even if you don't use it anywhere else)

move this

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    component: SomeComponent,
    matcher: () => { //your url matcher },
  }
,...
];
```

to

```js
export function yourUrlMatcher( //params ) { //your function here }

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    component: SomeComponent,
    matcher: yourUrlMatcher,
  }
,...
];
```